# Pandas 1.0.1 import error in pypy 7.3.0 (python3.6.9)

Tags: pandas, import, pypy

After Pandas was installed successfully in the environment of pypy 7.3.0 for windows 32bit (python3.6.9), I tried importing Pandas. But error message was printed

Steps running is below

1. type pypy in windows' CMD
2. import pandas

then, error message I have seen is as follows:

`(CMD) C:\Users\Hs> pypy`

> Python 3.6.9 (1608da62bfc7, Dec 23 2019, 12:38:24)
>   [PyPy 7.3.0 with MSC v.1911 32 bit] on win32
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

`>>>> import pandas`

> RPython traceback:
>     File "pypy_interpreter.c", line 40596, in BuiltinCode_funcrun_obj
>     File "pypy_objspace_std_7.c", line 22171, in W_UnicodeObject_descr_lower
>     File "pypy_objspace_std_7.c", line 39925, in _lower_unicode
>     File "rpython_rlib.c", line 15585, in _nonascii_unichr_as_utf8_append
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "C:\ProgramData\bin\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\site-packages\pandas__init__.py", line 31, in 
>       from pandas._libs import hashtable as _hashtable, lib as _lib, tslib as _tslib
>     File "C:\ProgramData\bin\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\site-packages\pandas_libs__init__.py", line 3, in 
>       from .tslibs import (
>     File "C:\ProgramData\bin\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\site-packages\pandas_libs\tslibs__init__.py", line 3, in 
>       from .conversion import localize_pydatetime, normalize_date
>     File "pandas_libs\tslibs\c_timestamp.pxd", line 7, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion
>     File "pandas_libs\tslibs\c_timestamp.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.c_timestamp
>     File "pandas_libs\tslibs\tzconversion.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.tzconversion
>     File "pandas_libs\tslibs\timedeltas.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas
>     File "pandas_libs\tslibs\offsets.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets
>     File "pandas_libs\tslibs\ccalendar.pyx", line 13, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.ccalendar
>     File "pandas_libs\tslibs\strptime.pyx", line 625, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime
>     File "pandas_libs\tslibs\strptime.pyx", line 530, in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.TimeRE.**init**
>     File "pandas_libs\tslibs\strptime.pyx", line 409, in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.LocaleTime.**init**
>     File "pandas_libs\tslibs\strptime.pyx", line 505, in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.LocaleTime.__calc_timezone
>   SystemError: unexpected internal exception (please report a bug): ; internal traceback was dumped to stderr

please consider that pypy doesn't support pandas formally as noted at pypy's homepage but I successfully installed pandas

Comment: Could you reformat your code paste with the code tag? It is difficult to read

Comment: I think the problem is that somehow on PyPy win32, `time.tzname` includes a `'\00` at the end. Thanks for the report, will try to fix.

Comment: code here, `import pandas`

Comment: when i typed this code `time.tzname` it was printed that
>> ('\Ufffffd6b\u0211\Ufffffe8e\Ufffffc79 \x20Ufffffc64 \x34Uffffffe0 \Uffffff83\Ufffffc23\x00', '\Ufffffd6b\x64\Ufffffe8e\Ufffffc79 \x63Ufffffc64 \x66Uffffffe0 \Uffffff83\Ufffffc23\x00') \x78\x30 \x27\x29

Comment: \x00 exist there. then how can I fix it?